# In the latest version of Arduino Desktop IDE, are there all features of Arduino Web Editor?

Tags: arduino-ide

I would like to know if there are always the latest features in Arduino Desktop IDE if I update it every day.

I mean if there is a new feature in Arduino Web Editor, can I get it on Arduino Desktop IDE?

Comment: A new GUI feature, or a new feature of the language / API?

Comment: Is it possible to know for both?

Comment: How are you updating it? The Arduino IDE beta build is actually a little more closely aligned with the Arduino Web Editor because they both use [arduino-preprocessor](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-preprocessor). The hourly build of the IDE does not currently use arduino-preprocessor (this will change as soon as some [serious bugs](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-preprocessor/issues) in arduino-preprocessor are resolved). Arduino Web Editor users are actually unknowing beta testers for the unfinished arduino-preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always get the same API features in both, because the API is separate to both of them - it's a plugin that's developed separately.

Would you get the same GUI facilities? No idea. Maybe - maybe not. It depends how useful they would be. You may get features added to the GUI that don't appear on the web. Or you may get the other way around. If they are essential to the operation of the system, though, you will get them added to both.